# How to check out if mb_send_email correctly send the email in php?

Tags: php, http, email, post

I have following simple email form which is sends data to `mb_send_mail`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/html;";
    $header .= "charset=\"utf-8\"\n";
    $to = 'testmyemailforphp@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Test email';
    $isSent = mb_send_mail($to, $subject, $_POST['message'], $header);
}
if ($isSent)
    $output = "the message was sent<br>";
 else
    $output = "some error<br>";
?>

<body>
    <?php
    if ($output)
        echo "<p>$output</p>";
    ?>
    <form method="POST">
        <textarea name="message"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Now the after inserting some txt and clicking the submit button, it will print the success message `the message was sent`. But in my email `testmyemailforphp@gmail.com` (created just for this purpose), I see no incomes, neihter after 15 minutes. So how can I test, if the function `mb_send_mail` is really something sending?

Comment: *"So how can I test, if the function mb_send_mail is really something sending?"* - You're already doing that with your conditional statement. If you got back "the message was sent", then mail has done its job. If you didn't receive the email, then something failed somewhere and could be next to impossible to know why, given you have mail access. See if error reporting picks anything up.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to do that and you should delete that comment. You could get hacked.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner this is just test mail

Comment: There's presumably a default "from" address in your php.ini. Is the server that you're running this on allowed (e.g. by SPF settings) to send mail on behalf of that address?

Comment: @GregSchmidt I have no idea how to configure php.ini. I have setup my lamp via `https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mariadb-php-lamp-stack-on-debian-10` tutorial and I am using `localhost` for it. Localhost cannot send email?